# Как открыть в Go-сервере статический HTML-файл по идентификатору в URL?

Tags: сервер, golang, url, роутинг

Как открыть в Go-сервере статический HTML-файл по идентификатору в URL?
Типа по URL www.site.com/blog/t5544 открыть файл $/www/site.com/page10.html
Такое вообще возможно?

Answer (score 1):

Возможно, конечно :)

Если я правильно понял, то нужно получить параметр из URL, открыть шаблон и передать туда этот параметр. Пакет `net/http` не умеет парсить URL, поэтому нужно будет воспользоваться внешним пакетом. Установим:

```bsh
go get github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter
```

Меньше слов, больше примеров:

```go
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  // Пакет net/http не умеет парсить параметры из URL, поэтому воспользуемся этим пакетом
  "github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter"
  "html/template"
  "net/http"
)

type responseData map[string]interface{}

func main() {
  // Создаем роутер
  router := httprouter.New()

  // Регистрируем пути
  router.GET("/test", func(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    _ = loadTemplate("test").Execute(response, responseData{})
  })

  // :id - и есть наш параметр
  router.GET("/user/:id", func(response http.ResponseWriter, request *http.Request, params httprouter.Params) {
    _ = loadTemplate("user").Execute(response, responseData{
      "user_id": params.ByName("id"),
    })
  })

  fmt.Println("We are alive on :8181")
  _ = http.ListenAndServe(":8181", router)
}

// Можно прочитать файл и отдать его содержимое, а можно загрузить файл как шаблон, передать туда параметры
// и отдать пользователю
func loadTemplate(tpl string) *template.Template {
  // Загружаем 
  return template.Must(template.ParseFiles(fmt.Sprintf("./page/%s.html", tpl)))
}
```

В `test.html` нет ничего интересного, а вот в `user.html` есть использование параметра:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
    Страница пользователя с ID {{ .user_id }}
</body>
</html>
```

После запуска пройдем по адресу `http://localhost:8181/user/100500`

UPD. Вероятно, я неправильно понял вопрос, исправляюсь
Отдать любой статичный файл, как подметили в комментарии, можно так:

```go
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "net/http"
)

func main() {

    http.Handle("/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("static")))

    fmt.Println("We are alive on :8181")
    _ = http.ListenAndServe(":8181", nil)
}
```

В директории static размещаются файлы, которые должны быть доступны извне

Comment: «Пакет `net/http` не умеет парсить URL» — простите. **что?**  Пожалуйста, не сбивайте новичков подобным.  Им всего лишь [`net/http.FileServer`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#FileServer) с обёрткой нужен.

Comment: @Ainar-G , а можно пример? Обёртки для http.FileServer(). А то я пытался, но не выходит...

Comment: @Ainar-G, действительно. Моя невнимательность. Поправил

Comment: @Norik_A, изменил ответ на правильный :)

Comment: Эмм.... Как отдать любой статический файл, я знаю. :) Лучше бы вернуть первоначальный пример. :) Он как раз был по вопросу...., я не успел затестить..

Comment: Мда.... Вот и поговорили.....

Comment: @Norik_A, не проблема. Изменил ответ, вернул первый вариант

Comment: Спасибо!  Вижу...

Comment: Код в вашем примере вставляет _определённый текст_ в **определённый файл**. Так?

Comment: Да, можно и так сказать

Answer (score 0):

```golang
type filesHandler struct {
    // Таблица "ID файла" и положения на диске.
    files map[string]string
}

func (h *filesHandler) ServeHTTP(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    var f = h.files[r.RequestURI]
    if f == "" {
        http.NotFound(w, r)
        return
    }

    http.ServeFile(w, r, f)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/T6rzOAvr1mE

Comment: А где тут http.FileServer()?

Comment: `http.ServeFile` — это почти то же самое, но позволяет выбрать файл.  Внутри они вызывают одну и ту же неэкспортированную функцию `serveFile`.

Comment: Речь про HTML-файл (содержащий подключенные файлы), который корректно откроется в браузере только http.FileServer()'ом. Не знаю причём тут http.ServeFile()...

Comment: Вы какие-то странные вещи говорите.  В *HTML* никаких «подключённых файлов» нету.  Ваш вопрос был «по адресу `x` отдать файл `y`».  Я написал вам код, который это делает.  Если он вас не устраивает, редактируйте и уточняйте вопрос, потому что на вопрос в его нынешнем виде мой код отвечает.

Comment: Всё в порядке с моим вопросом.

Comment: > В HTML никаких «подключённых файлов» нету. - а вот вы, похоже, тролль!